# Why 'numpy.int64' object is not callable here

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I would like to print the length of the value, but how there is such a error? Thx!

```
index = 1
for key in map1.keys():
    val = map1[key]
    if(index == 1):

        print(len(val))
    index = index+1
```

> 'numpy.int64'
>    object is not callable

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code and errors as images. They are text so paste them in the question and format accordingly.

Comment: How do you mean? Length of the value? Is it the number of digits? Please be clear and format your question accordingly.

Comment: Please, tell us how map1 looks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, @Eno!  Could you please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help identify the source of the error?  The image you posted does not contain enough information to tell us whence the values of the dict come.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the length of an integer, which you can't do in Python. You should do print(len(str(val))) if you really want to find the length of an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when you declare any of the predefined functions as a variable. In my case i declared `max` as a variable and assigned it a value. All of a sudden everything started to fail with the error `numpy.int64` is not callable, for all statements i execute with numpy library. So be careful when declaring variables. Make sure you avoid using `max`, `min`, `sum`, `abs` etc.,

To rectify the error i have to restart the python environment.